# How to do a pgdump with strings encoded?

Tags: postgresql, dump, pg-dump

When I perform a dump with pg_dump tool, with a "flat" sql format, pg_dump create a regular sql file but the restoration with pg_restore fails because the strings are not escaped.
For example, single quotes used in strings are saved as single quotes, avoiding the correct parsing of the string and the entire file.

Is there a way to dump with character encoding and restore coorectly after ?

Comment: You are not supposed to restore plain sql dumps with `pg_restore` but `psql`.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgrestore.html